# Syntax error in JS when class is added

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

this is my code. It's giving me a syntax error when I go to add the "deleteitem" class but I'm not sure how to correct it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var url = "db-get.php";
    $("#userdata tbody").html("");
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
      $.each(data.orders, function (i, order) {
        var tblRow =
          "<tr id=" + order.id + ">" + "<td>" + order.id + "</td>" + "<td>" + order.Name + "</td>" + "<td>" + order.Company + "</td>" + "<td>" + order.Phone + "</td>" + "<td>" + order.Location + "</td>" + "<td><button class="deleteitem">Delete</button></td>" + "</tr>";
        $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use single quotes around anything enclosing double quotes:

```
... '<td><button class="deleteitem">Delete</button></td>' ...
```

Instead of:

```
... "<td><button class="deleteitem">Delete</button></td>" ...
```

The parser thinks the string ends after the first quote before deleteitem and crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the quotes wrong. You can't have double quotes both to limit the whole string and use it for the attribute value in the string. One way is to escape the quotes like this `\"` but I really prefer using single and double quotes, makes it much more readable.

Try this:

```
'<td><button class="deleteitem">Delete</button></td>'
```

IE use single quotes around the whole table cell code, then you can use double quotes around the attribute value (class name).

Answer (score 0):

change "deleteitem" to

```
\"deleteitem\"
```

so the " are properly escaped

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your quotes. Try

```
"<td><button class=\"deleteitem\">Delete</button></td>"
```